# Reference error .netportable 4.0 profile136 profile is not installed

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

Suddenly I started getting reference errors in my Portable Class Library projects,

When referencing System, System.Core, System.Xml I get

.netportable 4.0 profile136 profile is not installed

It used to work fine a few days ago so I'm not sure if a recent update would have caused this issue.  I did switch back and forth from stable to beta, and back to stable update channel.  Does anyone know what might be causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

Does this happens on MAC? you might need to reinstall Xamarin Studio